# How can I get Solitude out of war mode?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing xbox.

I'm a Stormcloak and just completed the quest to take Solitude:

> I killed General Tullius, went outside, listened to Ulfric's speech, watched him walk away with the other guy saying "we have a lot to do"

However. Solitude still has the combat music playing whenever I'm there, the icon for Solitude doesn't show up on my map for fast travel, and when I run up there I get a message when I go in the gate that I have to "complete defence of the city". The Blue Palace is locked (though I can break in). The rest of the town is back to normal - no fires, people walking around, etc. How can I get the war situation to end? Should I have talked to Ulfric again after his speech?

Comment: Related: [How to fix Skyrim combat music bug?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/147452/4797)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going and speaking to Ulfric in Windhelm made the icon appear again on my map.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry this is about 3 years late xD but this is for anyone else stuck in a permanent battle for solitude like thing.
If you have completed the quest and is still like it, then type in resetquest cwsiegeobj and the siege will stop.
I have yet to see any side effects from this but everything has returned to normal and the stormcloaks act like the quest is completed.

Comment: He mentions playing on Console (xbox), so no console available: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39955/is-there-a-way-to-use-console-commands-in-the-console-version-of-skyrim